# Projeto em JSF 2.3 com demora na conexão incial

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate

Estou fazendo um sistema usando Java1.8, JSF 2.3, hibernate 5.4.x e Tomcat 9, com padrão MVC e entitymanager.

O problema é que para salvar o primeiro objeto em um formulário, ele demora uns 3 a 5 segundos. Depois, tudo fica normal. Acredito que seja o start inicial do Entity. Isto é normal?

Desde já agradeço a ajuda dos amigos.

Comment: Sem ver o seu código-fonte ou ao menos os logs da aplicação, não dá para saber ao certo. No entanto, já vi vários casos onde o Hibernate só faz o mapeamento objeto-relacional na primeira tentativa de acesso ao banco, ocasionando um comportamento exatamente como o que você descreveu, então é bem provável que seja isso mesmo. Aliás, eu diria que o normal é ele fazer isso mesmo.

Comment: Fiz alguns testes e foi exatamente isto que descobri. Percebi isto por acaso. Como meu sistema inicializa no persistence.xml com um "create-and-drop", ele recria todas as entitys em cada reinicialização. Testei tirando este parametro e tudo voltou ao normal. Mas de qualquer forma, muito obrigado pela resposta.